# Is it feasible to run cuda and output screen respectively in different two cards?

Tags: debugging, cuda, gpu

I have two Nvidia cards,8600GT and 550GT ti. 
Can I set the 8600GT to output the screen and debug and make 550GT Ti run CUDA without SLI connector?

Comment: This is really off topic for StackOverflow, but the short answer is yes - you can use one card as the primary display and another as a dedicated compute device. This type of two card setup is actually mandatory if you want to use a source level debugger like cuda-gdb or Nsight.

Comment: Sometimes when I use just  one card to run heavy programs,the computer seems too busy to response.Then,the computer crashed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Call cudaSetDevice() to choose which device to run the CUDA code on.

Comment: And `cudaDeviceQuery()` can tell you which device ID is which.